# Comparing and extracting Rows

Tags: excel, vba

In my Workbook I have a number of sheets containing customer data. These sheets where extracted from a very large set of Master data and are split based on factors such as the record missing an email address, phone number or a department code.

What I need to guard against is those records that are contained in **multiple sheets**, I need to be-able to confirm that each record only occurs once across the different sheets. Is there a way to compare the Customer Number (the first Column in all the sheets) across the sheets,pinpoint duplicates and automatically remove these leaving one instance of each customer across the workbook?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is :). Usually we help here to solve issues not write complete solutions so I will share my recommended solution for you.

As your data is probably structured nicely instead of writing a long piece of VBA use a SQL statement e.g.

```
SELECT S1.Col1 FROM [Sheet1$] AS S1, [Sheet2$] AS S2 WHERE S1.Col1 = S2.COL2
```

You can extend it to other worksheets using a union statement. Something like this:

```
SELECT S1.Col1 FROM [Sheet1$] AS S1, [Sheet2$] AS S2 WHERE S1.Col1 = S2.COL2
UNION ALL
SELECT S1.Col1 FROM [Sheet1$] AS S1, [Sheet2$] AS S3 WHERE S1.Col1 = S3.COL2
```

To get the list of ID that repeat between sheet 1 and 2-3.

How to use SQL in Excel? See my Add-In: http://blog.tkacprow.pl/excel-sql-add-in-free/
or use Microsoft Query (Data-> External Data etc.).

Then to delete the duplicates use some VBA to loop through the record which you want to delete and delete them.